# Projecting sphere surface onto circle while preserving area?

Tags: calculus, geometry, multivariable-calculus, differential-geometry

Consider all the points on the surface of a unit-radius sphere, lets call it $\mathbb S$.  ($\mathbb S$ is also precisely the set of all unit vectors.)

$$\mathbb S : \begin{bmatrix} x \\ y \\ z \end{bmatrix} \in \mathbb R^3 : x^2+y^2+z^2 = 1$$

Now consider a set $\mathbb C$, the set of all points inside a circle.

$$\mathbb C : \begin{bmatrix} u \\ v \end{bmatrix} \in R^2 : u^2 + v^2 < 1$$

I want to create a function from $\mathbb S$ to $\mathbb C$ of the form:

$$f : \mathbb S \to \mathbb C$$

$$g : \mathbb R \to \mathbb R$$

$$f(\begin{bmatrix} x \\ y \\ z \end{bmatrix}) = \frac{g(x)\begin{bmatrix} y \\ z \end{bmatrix}}{\sqrt{y^2+z^2}}$$

Let's suppose:

$$g(x) = \frac{1 - x}{2}$$

Then the projection would look like this:

[image]

The hemisphere with $x>1$ would be projected into the center of the circle, and the hemisphere with $x<1$ would be stretched around it. (Ignore the two points $(\pm 1,0,0)$ for now)

Assume the surface of the sphere has constant ("2D") density, how can we adjust the definition of $g$ such that the resulting projected circle also has constant density?

Clearly the "strength" of the sphere at x is proportional to $\sqrt{1-x^2}$, which is the radius of the slice of the sphere at that point.

And the "strength" of the circle at $g(x)$ is proportional to $g(x)$, which is the radius of the circle projecting that slice into.

But I can't quite put those two things together?

Comment: Disk, not circle. The circle is a curve.

Comment: @TedShifrin Maybe "circle" is a too straight traslation from spanish, a "false friend" for a spanish speaker. Check [this](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/C%C3%ADrculo) and [this](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Circunferencia) You can expect to see that mistake often.

Comment: @Rafa, yes, and it’s used in mathematically imprecise situations in English too. The first link you gave me said literally that a circle is a planar region delimited by a circle; lovely.

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps you should use the word “clearly” more sparingly :-)

The $2$-sphere in $3$ dimensions has the remarkable property (which no other hypersphere has) that slices of equal width have equal surface area; in other words, that the surface area is proportional to the width of the slice.

The circle with radius $g(x)$ has surface area proportional to $g(x)^2$, so you need $g(x)^2\propto1-x$. The factor of proportionality can be determined by equating the total areas: $\pi g(-1)^2=4\pi$. So the factor of proportionality is $2$, and the solution is $g(x)=\sqrt{2(1-x)}$, that is,

\begin{eqnarray}
f\left(\left[\matrix{x\\y\\z}\right]\right)
&=&
\sqrt{\frac{2(1-x)}{y^2+z^2}}\left[\matrix{y\\z}\right]
\\
&=&
\sqrt{\frac{2(1-x)}{1-x^2}}\left[\matrix{y\\z}\right]
\\
&=&
\sqrt{\frac2{1+x}}\left[\matrix{y\\z}\right]
\;.
\end{eqnarray}

Comment: I don't think this solution is correct.  For example, if we look at `f([0,0,1])` (ie `x = 0, y = 0, z = 1`) then by your formula we get a result of `[0,sqrt(2)]` (ie `u = 0, v = 1.41`) which is not inside the unit circle.  ?  What do I miss?